# Remove default Google Chrome microphone icon in search field with CSS or Jquery?

Tags: google-chrome, microphone

Is it possible to remove the default Google Chrome microphone icon in a search field using CSS or Jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at `https://google.com`, you will see that what drives the microphone icon is `x-webkit-speech=""`

I did an inspect element and removed that bit and the microphone icon no longer shows up. If you do not want to show the microphone in your website, perhaps you can try not including the `x-webkit-speech` bit?

`<input id="gbqfq" class="gbqfif" name="q" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" style="border: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: auto; width: 100%; background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw%3D%3D); background-color: transparent; position: absolute; z-index: 6; left: 0px; outline: none; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; " x-webkit-speech="" x-webkit-grammar="builtin:search" lang="en" dir="ltr" spellcheck="false">`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use pseudo elements to hide the microphone icon (this works in older versions of Chrome, I'm not sure if `x-webkit-speech` is even supported anymore as there is the much more capable Web Speech API now in Chrome).

I have been using this CSS whenever I've needed to hide the icon

```
input::-webkit-input-speech-button {
    display : none;
}
```

Though as the other answer on this question suggests, there's probably not much point in using the `x-webkit-speech` attribute if you don't want the microphone displayed. HTML5Rocks has a good article at http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API if you want to learn about the Web Speech API, which includes speech synthesis as well as speech recognition.